# merge multiple rows to one in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following result set:

```
ID          P1Score P2Score P3Score
===================================
22117617    NULL    50      NULL
22117617    1       NULL    NULL    
22117617    NULL    NULL    40
```

What I want to do is, merge these rows into one.

I want to place value of P1Score in the P1score column, same with P2score and P3score.

How would one achieve this?

Comment: to clarify: OP want to get 1 row containing 3 scores in his result set instead of 3 rows containing 1 score.

Comment: Can you show your initial SQL query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ID,
max(ISNULL(P1Score,0)),
max(ISNULL(P2Score,0)),
max(ISNULL(P3Score,0))
from [Score] group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use group by with sum() function since suppose if you have multiple scores for single Id then sum would be appropriate.

```
SELECT ID
    ,sum(P1Score) AS P1Score
    ,sum(P2Score) AS P2Score
    ,sum(P3Score) AS P3Score
FROM [Score]
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or up, you can use MAX with OVER:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                MAX(P1Score) OVER (ORDER BY ID) P1Score,
                MAX(P2Score) OVER (ORDER BY ID) P2Score,
                MAX(P3Score) OVER (ORDER BY ID) P3Score
FROM YourTable
```

Output:

```
ID          P1Score P2Score P3Score
22117617    1       50      40
```

Or even pivoting:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
UNPIVOT (
    [Values] FOR PScores IN (P1Score, P2Score, P3Score)
) unp
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR PScores IN (P1Score, P2Score, P3Score)
) piv
```